# Outputting MIDI sound from Python Mido library on Mac

Tags: python, macos, midi, mido

I'm trying to output a note to my computers internal speakers using python with the mido library.  I have a mac, and I've learned that by default you need to go through the IAC Driver to output any sound to the speakers.  I enable the IAC Driver and searched for the correct output using the command:

```
>>> mido.get_output_names()
['IAC Driver Bus 1']
```

From there I created the simple script:

import mido

```
def main():

    outport = mido.open_output('IAC Driver Bus 1')
    outport.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=60, velocity = 100))

main()
```

note=60 should be outputting middle C and velocity is the volume.

However no sound is being produced at all.  I'm assuming the port must be recognized as I get no errors but again there is no sound being output.  Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: The IAC driver routes the messages to some other application. Try GarageBand.

Comment: When I ran the command mido.get_output_names() IAC Driver Bus 1 is the only result displayed.  Is there a way to set garageband as an output port?

Comment: You have to go through IAC from both applications.

Comment: Could you please give more detail on how to do this?  I've never used IAC or done any MIDI programming before, having a lot of difficultly finding clear instructions online as to how to set this up.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Screenshot of Audio MIDI Setup app]

1. Open the Audio MIDI Setup app
2. Choose *Window > Show MIDI Studio*
3. Double-click on *IAC Driver*
4. Check *Device is online*
5. Start Garage Band and add a software MIDI track
6. Test that it's working with your keyboard

Now you should hear something when you run your code.